# Call to a member function getHost() on null but it is not null

Tags: symfony, variables, service, twig, global

I have a service and call it on every page. I get the Error: Call to a member function getHost() on null but when I dump the request I get the Host. It renders the error message after my Template.

Here is my Service:

```
class ClientService
{
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
 */
private $em;

/**
 * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
 */
private $request;

/**
 * @var \Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
 */
private $router;

public function getEm()
{
    return $this->em;
}

public function __construct(EntityManager $em, RequestStack $request) {
    $this->setEm($em);
    $this->request = $request;
}

public function getRequest()
{
    return $this->request;
}

public function getData()
{
    $client = $this->getEm()
        ->getRepository(Client::class)
        ->findOneBy(['serveralias' => $this->getRequest()->getCurrentRequest()->getHost()]);

    return $client;
}


}
```

Comment: Start by renaming $request to $requestStack,  Just to keep you from pulling your hair out later. How exactly is the service being called?  From a listener?  Injected into something else?  Seems like it is being called too early in the processing cycle before the request stack is initialized.

Comment: I call the service only as a global Twig variable.

Comment: That does not tell me anything useful.  Show exactly where ClientService::getData() is being called.  I'm guessing you are actually trying to injects the results of getData into your global twig variable?  In which case it is getting called in the boot process before request stack is initialized.

Comment: I found it only one time in a registration listener. Where I check if the Client is already registered. I think the getData() function is not the Problem. The reason why I get the error ist, that Symfony don't get the Host.

Comment: If you say so.  If you look in index.php or app.php you will see that request always has the host and soon as it it created.  And the error message clearly shows that current request is not set.  But we are making progress.  Before you said the service was only accessed from a twig global.  Now we have a listener involved.  I'm out but maybe somebody else can persuade you to share the code necessary to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, checking [RequestStack](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/RequestStack.php#L59) api you can see that `getCurrentRequest()` might also return `null` probably when there's no request at all.

Therefore, before calling a function on something that might be `null`, I would always check its current value

```
public function getData()
{
    if (!$currentRequest = $this->getRequest()->getCurrentRequest()) return null;
    $client = $this->getEm()
        ->getRepository(Client::class)
        ->findOneBy(['serveralias' => $currentRequest->getHost()]);

    return $client;
}
```